# highchart series push from ajax

Tags: highcharts

ive try to graph date and a value, this is my code:

```
function getDaily(vsatid){
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "daily_graph.php",
     data: "id=" + vsatid,
     success: function(obj1){
     options.series[0].data = obj1.date;
     options.series[1].data = obj1.ebno;
     }
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
});}
```

can anyone tell me how i suppose to push the series so i can get x as datetime and y as value.
below is my data parsed from mysql database to json by using json_encode.

> [{"date":"1363700566","ebno":8.04},{"date":"1363701638","ebno":8.02},{"date":"1363705226","ebno":7.93},{"date":"1363709087","ebno":7.65},{"date":"1363712661","ebno":7.69},{"date":"1363716221","ebno":7.44},{"date":"1363719708","ebno":7.19},{"date":"1363723254","ebno":6.97},{"date":"1363726853","ebno":6.99},{"date":"1363730481","ebno":7.04},{"date":"1363734045","ebno":6.92},{"date":"1363737697","ebno":7.07},{"date":"1363741201","ebno":7.27},{"date":"1363744878","ebno":7.35},{"date":"1363748625","ebno":7.48},{"date":"1363752211","ebno":0},{"date":"1363755741","ebno":7.69},{"date":"1363759347","ebno":7.76},{"date":"1363762894","ebno":7.83},{"date":"1363766640","ebno":7.82},{"date":"1363770121","ebno":7.82},{"date":"1363773789","ebno":7.69},{"date":"1363777209","ebno":6.78},{"date":"1363780874","ebno":8.15}]

all answer will appreciate..
regards
mahrus

Comment: How many series do you have ? That json example looks like one dataseries to me, but you are referring to series[0] and series[1] in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Each datapoint should be defined as:

```
Var mydata = [[1363700566000,8.04], [1363701638,8.02] ]
```

Alternatively, you can specify more point options using this form:

```
Var my data = [{x:1363700566000,y:8.04}, {x:1363701638,y:8.02} ]
```

Note, dates are specified in milliseconds, so you need to multiply yours by 1000.

```
Options.series[0].data = mydata
```

Comment: hi steve, thanks for your quick response. can u give an example with the highchart code to push the series.  thx

Comment: user2191129 - your code is good example, just update your outputted JSON according to SteveP answer. Also, make sure that your dates are not string - should be numbers (like in above example).

Answer (score 0):

You dates should be timestamp, so you should use parseFloat() functon to transorm string to number, then multiply by 1000 to achieve appropriate javascript timestamp format.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
chart.series[0].addPoint(obj1.date);
chart.series[1].addpoint(obj1.ebno)


//     options.series[0].data = obj1.date;
//     options.series[1].data = obj1.ebno;

by using two series u will get 2 diff x values for two diff series
if u want to get x,y val for same series 

parse the obj1 to json . or 
add

               type:"GET",
                   url: "delete",
            //       dataType:"json",
                       data:chart.series[0].data,

try
 $.each(obj1,function(index,object){
 chart.series[0].addPoint(object);
 });                
  // will iterate all the objects and add it to series

where obj1 should contain
[{"x":"1363700566","y":8.04}
```